# State not updating inside of render

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to bind elements using `setAttribute`. It works, except it will not allow me to change the value.

Basically I want to pass a value from state as the value in the input.

Currently, the state does NOT update inside the render. It only takes the initial state. In the render, my 'console.log' only fires once.

The correct `this.state.answer` does appear in componentDidUpdate (and did Mount).

I have put this on JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/91132/

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
  cf = null
  state = {answer:''}

  componentDidMount(){
    this.refs.q1.setAttribute('cf-questions', "How are you?")
    this.cf = window.cf.ConversationalForm.startTheConversation({
      formEl: this.refs.form,
      context: document.getElementById("cf-context"), // <-- bind this to an element instead of html body
      flowStepCallback: (dto, success, error) => {
      // dto.text contains the value being passed to the form

      // State appears in console.log
      // dto.text = 'blah' + this.state.answer 
      // above ONLY passes 'blah'
        success()  
      },
    });
  }
componentDidUpdate(props) {
     this.refs.q1.setAttribute("value", this.state.answer);
  }
  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ answer: 'X' });
  }
  render() {
console.log('a change', this.state.answer)
// Only fires once
    return (
      <div>
      <button onClick={this.onChange} className='but'> onChng </button>
        <div id="cf-context" >
          <form id="form" className="form" ref="form">
          <select ref="q1" type="radio" id="links">
              <option value="X">X</option>
              <option value="Y">Y</option>
            </select>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Which module are you using for DropDown?

Comment: I just updated the OP, for the sake of simplicity it's an onClick button. But point is, I want to pass the value from state. Do I have to do something like `<div ref={div => this.handleDivRef(div)}/>` ??

Comment: Where do you need the state to be passed?

Comment: It could pass as the value to the `<option value={this.state.answer}` or the dfo.text inside the `flowStepCallback` function

Comment: Can you update for fiddle for this current condition?

Comment: This is the latest fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/91162/

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the issue is within the componentDidMount() method.

I am not sure about what you have been doing.  But i guess you are setting the scope of the form Element within those particular div "cf-context".

So even after the state is updated, it takes value 'this' from particular scope which has been set.  Try moving the scope even further up towards the top of DOM

I am not sure this is right.  Please try

Comment: Please provide an example of this. I tried what you said, but it is not clear